# How do I write this query in Rails without Arel

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to achieve this :

```
    where(
        "(memberships.id IN (?) AND memberships.user_id == ?)
         OR (memberships.user_id == ? AND communities.hidden == ?)",
           m, user.id, nil, false)
```

This is returning an error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 77 OR memberships.user_id == NULL AND communities.hidden == 0)' at line 1: SELECT DISTINCT `communities`.* FROM `communities` LEFT JOIN `memberships` ON `communities`.`id` = `memberships`.`community_id` AND `memberships`.`user_id` = 77 WHERE `communities`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (memberships.id IN (NULL) AND memberships.user_id == 77 OR memberships.user_id == NULL AND communities.hidden == 0)
```

I don't want to use Arel

Comment: It would help to know version of Rails you're using. Rails 5 provides an `or` method that is NOT the one provided by Arel. If you're on Rails 5 it's powerful because it will actually keep you from writing any SQL in your code and eliminate the chance of getting ill-formed SQL errors in your Rails code. If you're not on Rails 5, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using double equal sing, whereas should use single:

```
where("(memberships.id IN (?) AND memberships.user_id = ?) OR (memberships.user_id = ? AND communities.hidden = ?)", m, user.id, nil, false)
```

Other than that the query looks valid to me (I suppose you're doing some kind of JOIN (using `joins()` or `includes()` before `where` clause)).

Comment: OMG thanks man, I can't believe I was doing that.